# Getting MaxRequestDurationExceeded error when try to read the table range

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When trying to get the range of the table using Graph API `/items/{workbookId}/workbook/tables/{tableName}/range?$select=address`, we are getting an error immediately with the following details

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "MaxRequestDurationExceeded",
        "message": "We're sorry. We couldn't finish what you asked us to do because it was taking too long.",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "gatewayTimeoutUncategorized",
            "message": "The service wasn't able to complete the request within the time limit.",
            "innerError": {
                "code": "MaxRequestDurationExceeded",
                "message": "We're sorry. We couldn't finish what you asked us to do because it was taking too long."
            },
            "date": "2023-01-06T14:45:21",
            "request-id": "4b6b5b18-e879-451a-b480-107a29240f19",
            "client-request-id": "4b6b5b18-e879-451a-b480-107a29240f19"
        }
    }
}
```

We have verified that data in the Excel is within the limits provided in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

We have product that writes data to Excel on schedule. As part of that solution, we read the range of the table and clear it before writing. When we make a request to get range, it should return the proper range instead of error

Comment: How many rows does the table have?

Comment: There are around 5000 rows in the table